# Use a database value to call a variable with the same name

Tags: c#, database, foreach

I need to update a table called `Calculated` in my database, but because I have so many values that I have stored in my system as variables to add/update in the table, I created a separate table in the database called `Database Relationships`.

This `Database Relationships` table has a column called `Calculated Value` which holds all the field names of the `Calculated` table. The other column, `System Field` holds all the names of variables that I have created and given values to, which are of all `string` type and that relate to the corresponding `Calculated Value`

So by using a `FOREACH` loop

```
OleDbDataAdapter relationshipAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(relationshipCmd);
DataTable relationshipTable = new DataTable();
relationshipAdapter.Fill(relationshipTable);

string update = "Update [Calculated] SET ";
int i = 0;
int len = relationshipTable.Rows.Count;
foreach (DataRow drr in relationshipTable.Rows)
{
    string calc = drr["Calculated Field"].ToString();
    var sys = drr["System Field"].ToString();
    if (i == len - 1)
    {
        update += "[" + calc + "] = " + sys + ";";
    }
    else
    {
        update += "[" + calc + "] = " + sys + ", ";
    }
i++

 }
 update += "WHERE [NSN] = '" + NSN + "';";
 OleDbCommand updateCmd = new OleDbCommand(update);
```

But this is not working, because after some debugging(?) I did a simple `Console.WriteLine(sys)` and it would print out the string in the `System Field` column, instead of the variable with the same name in the system.

I am currently using Microsoft Access as my database platform.

Comment: what do you mean by variable of the same name in the system? Where are those defined or scoped? I don't see any such variables in the code.

Comment: You said that in the table DataBaseRelationships you have two columns that both hold the names. Where do you want to insert the values then?

Comment: I didnt add them to the question,because there are like... 112 of them. 

What I mean by variables of the same name, is that for example, I create a variable called `king`, with a value of "George". And so, this variable `king` needs to be stored in the table called `Calculated`, under the field `King's Name`. But because I have over 112 of these variables, creating an `UPDATE` statement will be a bit too large, and hard to keep track of.

Comment: So i decided to create a seperate table called `Database Relationships`, which stores `King's Name` in the `Calculated Field` and `king` as the `System Field` within the table `Database Relationships`. So now, I want to be able to use a `FOREACH` loop to iterate through this table, and create an `UPDATE` statement. 

BUT the problem is, that the `System Field` name I am trying to print into my `UPDATE` statement, is showing the field name of `king`, instead of "George".

Comment: I've added an answer with the assumption that the variables are available in the scope where you're generating the Sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think having "intermediate" table for temporary storing values in runtime for future saving in another table sounds little bid complicated for me.

If you want to map variables at runtime with column name in the database - use dictionary for example:

```
Dictionary<string, string> myValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();
```

Using in the application:

```
myValues["SomeColumn"] = "your value";
```

Then saving data to database will be:

```
var updateCmd = new OleDbCommand();
var query = new StringBuilder();
foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> value in myValues)
{
    string columnName = value.Key;
    query.AppendLine($", {columnName} = ?");
    var param = new OleDbParameter("@v", value.Value); 
    // Name of parameter not important, only order
}

if(query.Length > 0)
{
    query.Remove(0, 1); // Remove first ',' character
    query.Insert("Update [Calculated] SET ");
    query.AppendLine("$WHERE [NSN] = '{NSN}';");
}

updateCmd.CommandText = query.ToString();
```

Very important: you need to use `OleDbParameter` for passing values to the query.

Answer (score 0):

In you foreach loop, use this:

```
if (i == len - 1)
{
    update += "[" + calc + "] = " + this.GetType().GetProperty(sys).GetValue(this, null)+ ";";
}
else
{
    update += "[" + calc + "] = " + this.GetType().GetProperty(sys).GetValue(this, null)+ ", ";
}
```

The code above assumes that the variables are scoped in the same scope where you are generating your Sql.

Answer (score -1):

In loop , you use the condition:

```
if (i == len - 1)
```

but you never change "len" or "i" value in the code.

Comment: Yes, I hav realized that, and have made an edit but that has nothing to do with the question I asked